# How can I return True if x is in either of multiple lists?

Tags: python, list, return

```py
>>> list1 = ['yes', 'yeah']
>>> list2 = ['no', 'nope']
>>> 'no' in list2
True
>>> 'no' in list1
False
>>> 'no' in (list1, list2)
False
>>> 'no' in (list1 and list2)
True
>>> 'yes' in (list1 and list2)
False #want this to be true
>>> 'yes' in (list1 or list2)
True
>>> 'no' in (list1 or list2)
False #want this to be true
>>>
```

As you can see, I'm getting nowhere.

How can I make it so that it returns true if x or y are in either lists?

Comment: I think it would be really helpful for you to type all of the the right-hand arguments you're using above into the python interpreter to see what they return. That might help you understand why none of these approaches worked.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that using `any`:

```
>>> any('yes' in i for i in (list1, list2))
True
```

Or, just concatenate the lists:

```
>>> 'yes' in list1+list2
True
```

Comment: I am a damn idiot for not thinking of concatenating. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

I think the best balance between succinct code and efficiency here would probably be using [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
import itertools
'no' in itertools.chain(list1, list2)
```

The `chain` function returns an iterator that produces the values of each list in succession. The result is similar to concatenating all the lists together, but without the added overhead of actually creating one massive list.

Another nice feature is that you can pass a list of lists to `chain` and [unpack it with the `*` operator](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists):

```
all_lists = [list1, list2]
'no' in itertools.chain(*all_lists)
```

Comment: Instead of `itertools.chain(*all_lists)`, you should probably use `itertools.chain.from_iterable(all_lists)`.

Comment: @SvenMarnach - I saw that in the docs (never used it before), but it seemed like that was really just added to support infinite iterators. Is there a significant performance difference otherwise? I only use Python occasionally, but it seems like sticking to `*` would be more "pythonic" if there isn't a serious performance implication.

Comment: Using `*` forces the immediate evaluation of the outer iterator.  Using `itertools.chain.from_iterable()` evaluates everything lazily.  For code that is supposed to work on generic iterators, that is  preferable.  If you know you are operating on medium-sized lists, it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`any` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any).

```
>>> any('no' in x for x in (list1, list2))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

`any` is generally the way to go, but there is also this simple expression:

```
>>> x = 'yes'
>>> (x in list1) or (x in list2)
True
>>> x = 'yep'
>>> (x in list1) or (x in list2)
False
```

This has the benefit of short cutting evaluation of the expression if `x` is in `list1`, whereas the `any` approach will iterate over both lists every time.